# How to define a range of cells on Conditional Formatting in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office, conditional-formatting

I want to apply one rule in a range of cells. In *Conditional Formatting Rules Manager*, under *Applies to* form, you can define this range by typing e.g.

```
$F$3:$F$152
```

But, **is there any way for the rule to be applied in a range of odd/even rows or by two columns**, in order to avoid selecting the cells with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "New Formatting Rule" dialog box, under Select a Rule Type, click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

For odd/even rows use the below condition

=EVEN(ROW())=ROW()

or

=ODD(ROW())=ROW()

For odd/even Columns use the below condition

=ODD(COLUMN())=COLUMN()

or

=EVEN(COLUMN())=COLUMN()

Found this information from the below link:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-conditional-formatting-to-format-even-and-odd-rows/